# Error installing Openmage (Undefined index: process)

Tags: magento, composer-php

Friends, I am trying to install Openmage and getting the following error:

```
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Package operations: 2 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Downloading aoepeople/composer-installers (v0.0.4)
  - Installing aoepeople/composer-installers (v0.0.4): Extracting archive
    Install of aoepeople/composer-installers failed


  [ErrorException]
  Undefined index: process
```

Have you ever exeperienced such an error? My `composer version is 2.0.6` and the `PHP versIon is 7.3.27`.This is how my composer.json looks like in case you guys want to take a look at it:

```
{
    "require": {
        "aoepeople/composer-installers": "*",
        "openmage/magento-lts": "19.4.6"
    }
}
```

Any idea how could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Friends,

I have just found a solution: the function "proc_open" was disabled in mys php.ini. Changing this solved my problem.